# iphone: customise cell.accessoryType

Tags: xcode

hi am doing an iphone twitter app with json and i am wondering if it is possible to set the 
cell.accessoryType to a image in UITableView? or possible move the image to the right hand side...any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just use the `accessoryView` property of UITableViewCell and assign a `UIImageView`:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fileNameOfYourImage.jpg"]; //or wherever you take your image from
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
cell.accessoryView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

Comment: it is kinda what i am looking for...but it doesnt seem to link together with the json...trying to do something like http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html. but the image is on a weblink

Answer (score 2):

No need to use imageview, just provide this for simple arrow.

cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;